# How to query Realtime Database to get objects ordered by time for a specific key

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an events node, where each event has a queue full of objects with specific keys. I am trying to use my server to get the keys of all events where a queue contains a specific key, ordered by time. This is my data structure:

```
{
    "events" : {
        "6Pl5x3KrDgOPxwEQq5yD" : {
            "queue" : {
                "aIcQtBOGP4eAgZvxh0emaHGCMNf1" : {
                    // Details
                },
                // More queuers
             }
        },
        "08Gnr1pbCQETXeRyRG349" : {
            "queue" : {
                "8Gnr1pbCQETXeRyRG349" : {
                    // Details
                },
                // More queuers
             }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I was searching for all events whose queue contained the key `aIcQtBOGP4eAgZvxh0emaHGCMNf1` in the data above, I would retrieve back `6Pl5x3KrDgOPxwEQq5yD`.

How can I do that using Node.js?

Comment: Hi there, "6Pl5x3KrDgOPxwEQq5yD" is this event Id ? or auto generated?

Comment: @MuruGan Yeah it is the id of the event. It is autogenerated when I create a new event.

Comment: to my understanding, you have list of events and in that you have queues for events attendees. Something like that?

Comment: @MuruGan Yep that is correct, so I'm trying to see all the events which a person is in the queue for

Comment: what best you can do is pull out the queue from the events because when you want the events alone but still you will get the queues list so it's downloading excess data.

Comment: First of all i want how will query the firebase.database().ref('/events/' + '/' + 'your eventId' +'/queues' + 'attendees Id'). how will you perform this ?

Comment: @MuruGan Ah yeah, true it'll get the whole list of data wont it. I guess I could just store the ids of the events that the user has joined somewhere else. But I would like them to be sorted by date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173066/discussion-between-murugan-and-tometoyou).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database can order/filter on properties that are on a known path under each child node of the location where you run the query. You're trying to filter on a dynamic path, which isn't possible.

You'll typically want to add an extra data structure to allow the lookup you want, e.g. a top-level list with the queue ids as keys, and then their event id as the value.

```
"events": {
    ...
},
"queues": {
    "aIcQtBOGP4eAgZvxh0emaHGCMNf1": "6Pl5x3KrDgOPxwEQq5yD",
    "8Gnr1pbCQETXeRyRG349": "08Gnr1pbCQETXeRyRG349"
}
```

Now you can look up whatever event somebody is queued for.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested).
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)